# How to capture a screenshot of other Android applications from an app without root?

Tags: android

I want to capture a screen shot of Android applications that are running on my phone.

I tried using the [ScreenShot UX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.shotux&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5saXZlb3Yuc2hvdHV4Il0.) application. This can be done on an unrooted phone also. 
Any idea of how to get the screen shot of the application in Android from a service that runs in the background?

I want my Service to capture screen periodically and send to a server.

Comment: by pressing lock/power button & home/back button at a same time

Comment: I want the code for doing it.

Comment: You should mention that in your question, it sounded like you were off-topic (though you're not)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screenshot Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android)

Comment: That post tells how to create snapshot of a view from the application itself. I want to take the screen shot from a service, irrespective of application

Comment: take the whole linear layout in drawing cache and draw view onto canvas and save it to bitmap , but you have to enable the drawingcache(`view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`) of that view.

Comment: @mak_just4anything this can be done only in the same activity. I want to take the screen shot of another application from my service

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [Android-screenshot-library](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/), enables to programmatically capture screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root access privileges.

Comment: Can i run the program without the Desktop application. In the ScreenshotService.java there is a method retreiveRawScreenshot(). It is connecting to a native application. Is that native application running in a PC.  http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/source/browse/demo/src/pl/polidea/asl/ScreenshotService.java

Comment: @Abi NO!  Read upon this : http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/UserGuide

Comment: The above post is also taking from the application. I want to run a service background which takes the screen shot of applications that is running on the phone and send to a server.

Comment: @Abi AFAIK If you want to take the screenshot of your current device screen (any application)(I suppose this is what you are looking for) then you need to have root permission.

Comment: It is possible without root permission.I checked the ScreenShot UX application. It is doing without root permission. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.shotux&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5saXZlb3Yuc2hvdHV4Il0.

Comment: @Abi Read upon the description of Screenshot UX, it clearly says _May require a rooted phone._ (I agree they say there are some exceptions)

Comment: Screenshot UX also works on unrooted phones, but only on selected models.

Comment: Is this library really only used for testing/debugging purposes? I can't see having this app in production with the pre-requisites needed to capture the screen.

Comment: @Abi did you get your answer? cuz i have the same problem :/

Answer (score 12):

The only way to take a screenshot of an app that is not your own is by getting the raw framebuffer. The framebuffer is usually located at `/dev/fb0` or `/dev/graphics/fb0`. On some devices (like an LG Optimus One) this can be accessed without root privileges, but on the majority (like a Nexus S) of them you need to be rooted for this. This is usually not allowed for security reasons, as a malicious app could take screenshots in the background and send them to a remote server, revealing information like email IDs and passwords, and in some cases bank account details.

Comment: Is it legal to take screenshot from a service. I want to use it for mobile tracking and not for any malicious app.

Comment: You can use a service to call a method in your app to take a screenshot of your own app, but using it with other apps is not possible without using the framebuffers. While you may have a legitimate use for it, many apps could abuse this, and hence it is by and large not available on non rooted devices.

Comment: +1 This is great thanks. I notice on my newer nexus devices 4.4.4+ the buffer is in neither of these locations - and idea where it may have moved to?

Answer (score 8):

As of Android 5.0+, you can use the new functionality in the SDK called [media projections](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) to do screen capture without root privileges.  There is sample code by Google available [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture).