# How to start screenshot service using a code in android 4.0

Tags: android, android-service

I want to know how to start screenshot service in android 4.0 using code. I know I can take screenshots using the power button. But I want to know how to do this using code.

Comment: See a complete rundown of possibilities here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462944/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-other-app-programmatically-without-root-permission/14718588#14718588

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, except maybe by rooted device users. Apps cannot take screenshots of other apps, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Is it still impossible ? I wanted to add this feature to my application.