# How to record touches and emulate them later on real devices (with ROOT if needed)?

Tags: android, macros, adb, monkeyrunner, emulation

### Background

the [**monkeyRunner**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) (and [**monkey**](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html)) is a nice tool to test out apps.

I have an idea of using it (or something similar) to record & emulate touches (and keys).

### The problem

The tool itself has some disadvantages:

- needs to be run on an emulator or on a device that is connected to a PC.
- needs adb.
- it needs that you type it exactly what to do , which requires a lot of patience and trial&error in order to find out what to write.
- has limitations on how many devices to run (since it needs to be connected to a PC).
- needs customization of each device (where to put the touches, for example).
- not intuitive, especially for QA teams.

### The question

Is it possible to use this tool in order to record touches (and keys) and later emulate them, even without using a computer? Maybe using a rooted device?

There are some advantages to having this ability:

1. It can help running tests on the go, and help QA teams to do tests in an easier way. You could have a tool that help you record macros for tests that will run on each new version, and some tests that are a bit random, ...
2. It can help making cool apps for power users, for example in order to help other people, remote control, macros,...
3. since you don't have to connect the device to the computer, you can run the macros on your app on multiple devices simultaneously .

Comment: Such a tool definitely would require root, unless Android has some dreadful security flaw. "you can run the macros on your app on multiple devices simultaneously" -- only if those devices have the same screen characteristics (resolution, density, etc.)

Comment: so you just confirm that this tool has another flaw that i haven't noticed... but why did you downvote the question? don't you see the potential it can get to both users and developers?

Comment: I didn't downvote the question.

Comment: Oh, ok. i wonder why do people downvote questions sometimes, but don't give any feedback as to why they did it. I can't learn anything from a downvote without any explanation... :(

Comment: You can take a look at [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) which at least frees you from having to provide touches and you can interact at a higher level.

Comment: @dtmilano i'm not sure i understand what this is about.