# Blur screen in Android Service

Tags: android

I'm creating an app with a service and my hope is to be able to blur the screen at any point, even when the app is in the background.

I've create a Service that, when the alert is called, creates a transparent View on the top of the Window. This is where I'm stuck though. There doesn't seem to be anyway to grab what is on the screen (without root) to create the blur effect and put it on this top view.

Is there anyway I can make this work? Is there anyway to grab the current screen outside of my app? Or, could I do something with the transparent view to make what's underneath blurry, like looking through a blurred window?

Comment: _Is there anyway to grab the current screen outside of my app?_ See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462944/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-other-app-programmatically-without-root-permission