# How to take snapshot of screen not only app in Android with code

Tags: java, android, snapshot

I've developed app that takes screenshot.
But it only takes snapshot of app. I want to take snapshot out of app.
I've researched answers but I don't find answer yet.
Here is my code.

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
saveImageToAppFolder(bitmap);
```

saveImagetoAppFolder is function that saves image to app folder.
That's not problem.
Is there anyway to take snapshot of screen?

Comment: You kind of need root permissions for that

Comment: Of course, I know that. But how can I get root permission?

Comment: Only if you have your device rooted,do you want to know how to screenshot using root?

Comment: I want to work it on all devices,

Comment: I feel sorry for you

Comment: OK, then can you share code which works only in rooted device?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14718588/3134215

Comment: I've also checked that, but no luck with it.

Comment: @Dima You can check my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To take screen shot of the device screen, **Only if you have root**
call the screencap binary like:

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor()
```

And to load that file into a bitmap,Use

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: where files are saved? If i want to save it app folder how can i do it?

Comment: The file is saved as img.png in sdcard

Comment: if you want to save it to any other directory,use the directory name or if you want it in app's data folder use Environment.getDataDirectory() or getFilesDir() instead of Environment.getExternalStorage()

Comment: @insomniac How can we get bitmap from that snapshot?

Comment: @insomniac Hi, I give  you bounty, btw I want you to find some answer without rooted phone.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know your code in saveImageToAppFolder is what but you can try this:

Note: you need set background of your app/activity to transparent (100%).

```
 //your code below is extractly
View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

  //try my code for save image file to storage   
  File imgFile = new File(imgPath);

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int imgQuality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, imgQuality , os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

Code to set transparent background:

//first: create theme xml below for transparent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

after set by this way:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">

</activity>
```

note: you can red more detail from here url: [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: this answer only screenshots the app screen not the whole phone like in the question

Comment: oh. This is my resolve: everyone can set bacground of your application to transparent so image captured is everything showing on screen and not your own activity

Comment: But app has many buttons and something other else. How can i set background transparent?

Comment: this is not works. The phone screen is not access