# Can i get the root view of activity where the user is currently

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I mean not in the app but anywhere, suppose user open my app and then moved it whatsapp can I get the root view of that activity.

I tried this

```
private Bitmap takeScreenshot(){
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

but it return the view of activity where it is defined, is it possible to obtain other app root view?

Comment: This would have serious security implications if it was allowed. May I ask why you want to? Just to take screenshots?

Comment: yes, i tried every question here on SO, but nothing is pointing out the good solution. That's why my mind got crazy and asked this question

Comment: Well [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11271436/10082297) seems to cover it pretty well, specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30586140/10082297) for Android 5.0+.